# linux + which tool can help to identify which eth in the Linux machines connected to which port in the cisco switch

Tags: linux, networking, cisco, scripting

I have a system with more than 50 different Linux machines (BLADE machines) with the following IP range

```
      165.23.1.21-165.23.1.64 ( each Linux machine have 4 eth - eth1,2,3,4)
```

The system connected to 4 Cisco switches via LANS cable

My target is to verify each eth in the Linux machine were this eth connected to which port in the switch

for example

./my_tool

```
   machine1 results


   linux_machine1_eth0  connected to switch_1_port_15
   linux_machine1_eth1  connected to switch_2_port_15
   linux_machine1_eth2  connected to switch_1_port_16
   linux_machine1_eth3  connected to switch_2_port_16


   machine2 results


   linux_machine2_eth0  connected to switch_1_port_22
   linux_machine2_eth1  connected to switch_4_port_7
   linux_machine2_eth2  connected to switch_1_port_23
   linux_machine2_eth3  connected to switch_4_port_8

   .
   .
```

My question which tool can help to identify which eth in the Linux machines connected to which port in the switch?

```
       remark -     1. the tool can be also script that runs on the Linux machines
                    2. we have access to the switch by telnet
```

Comment: do you have access to the cisco switch?

Comment: No I dont have access -:)

Comment: Than, there is no way i think. Sorry

Comment: I think you wrong
First we can create tool that search the MAC address on the eth and by show mac-address-table on the Cisco switch

Comment: But you need access to the switch for that! And you i thought you don't have that????

Comment: the access by telnet switch_address

Comment: Ok, it seems that you have answered your own question? Gather all mac addresses from every server, compare them with the cisco arp tables. If you provide more informations (edit your question) about how you could get the tables (SNMP/console) i'll try to help out with an script for doing that

Comment: so if I want to get info by SNMP on the linux machine , please advice how or which SNMP syntax I need to run on the Linux Machine in order to get info from the cisco switch

Comment: updated my answer with more information about the snmp way

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to go to each switch and issue the command

```
show mac-address-table
```

and make a note of the information provided. Then go to each linux machine and do something like

```
echo $(hostname); ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | awk '{print " "$1,$5}'
```

Now you have 2 lists to match up.

Comment: @Lain the problem is that I need user/password for the cisco switch , second there are some free tolls that I can use them so why to development new script/cod ?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a perl script using `Net::Telnet::Cisco` and `Net::OpenSSH` to automate this. I'll provide one here if i find some time today.

**UPDATE**

As asked by the questioner in a comment:
If you want to get the informations via SNMP, there is an excelent documentation in the cisco library: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00801c9199.shtml

In short: You need to merge the outputs of five `snmpwalk`s (where `crumpy` is you switchname)

```
snmpwalk -c public crumpy .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.3.1.1.2 # get vlan states
snmpwalk -c public@1 crumpy .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1     # get mac table
snmpwalk -c public@1 crumpy .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2     # get the switchport numbers for the vlans (here Vlan1)
snmpwalk -c public@1 crumpy .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2     # switchport to if number
snmpwalk -c public@1 crumpy .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1     # get the interface names
```

From the Docs:

```
6. Link a MAC address to the port on which the address was learned.

* From Step 1, the MAC address is:
      17.4.3.1.1.0.0.12.7.172.8 = Hex: 00 00 0C 07 AC 08

*  From Step 2, the bridge port tells that the MAC address belongs to bridge port number 13:
      17.4.3.1.2.0.0.12.7.172.8 = 13 

*  From Step 3, the bridge port number 13 has ifIndex number 2:
      17.1.4.1.2.13 = 2

*  From Step 4, the ifIndex 2 corresponds to port Fast Ethernet 0/1:
      ifMIB.ifMIBObjects.ifXTable.ifXEntry.ifName.2 = Fa0/1
```

Comment: Hi Thomas : I get the error about - snmpwalk -c public crumpy .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.3.1.1.2 getaddrinfo: crumpy Temporary failure in name resolution snmpwalk: Unknown host (crumpy) (Resource temporarily unavailable)

Comment: `crumpy` must be replaced by you switch name, sorry, forgotten, updated my post

Comment: Thomas ( I add the alias crumpy with the IP adddress in /etc/hosts ) and I get:  snmpwalk -c public crumpy .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.3.1.1.2
snmpwalk: No securityName specified

Comment: try to add `-v 1` to the `snmpwalk` command.

Comment: Thomas I have ping to crumpy (165.23.1.1) but I get : snmpwalk -v 1 -c public@1 165.23.1.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1 Timeout: No Response from 165.23.1.1

Comment: @Diana please think a little bit yourself. Is `SNMP` active on the Cisco switches? Read the documentation of your hard- and software please.

Comment: from Switch>show snmp  I see --> SNMP logging: disabled , than how to enable SNMP?

Comment: @Diana READ THE DOCUMENTATION OF YOUR HARDWARE! I'M NOT A HANDBOOK!

Answer (score 2):

If [CDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol) is enabled on the switch, you can give [`cdpr`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdpr/) a try. It's a simple program that you run on the servers and listen to the CDP announces.

```
petrus@seth:~$ sudo cdpr
cdpr - Cisco Discovery Protocol Reporter
Version 2.2.1
Copyright (c) 2002-2006 - MonkeyMental.com

1. eth0 (No description available)
2. wlan0 (No description available)
3. virbr0 (No description available)
<snip>
12. lo (No description available)
Enter the interface number (1-12):1
Using Device: eth0
Waiting for CDP advertisement:
(default config is to transmit CDP packets every 60 seconds)

Device ID
  value:  switch01           
Addresses
  value:  192.168.12.15 
Port ID
  value:  0/15
```

`cdpr` can also upload the details to a web server using a GET request.

Comment: cdpr is work via - SNMP? , need to run cdpr
on linux machine?

Comment: @Diana : `cdpr` runs on linux machines indeed. And if I understand you correctly, no there is no SNMP involved. CDP is another network protocol.

Comment: If CDP is enabled you can simply dump the network traffic and listen for broadcasts. In these broadcasts you will see the name, module and port of the cisco switch/router.

Comment: @Nils if CDP isnt enabled , so in this case we can enable this protocol from the cisco switch ? , if yes how ( by which cisco command ? )

Comment: @Diana: I am no cisco-admin - but it is propably somewhere in the manual...

Comment: @Nils , So maybe someone else can answer on this question I cant find from my Cisco switch , info about CDP protocol and how to enable CDP,

Answer (score 1):

[OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) does this well through its [Linkd feature](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Linkd), automatically discovering links between nodes through SNMP, CDP and via routing information. It also allows you to create [topology maps](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Maps).

The switch's links page looks like this:
[image]

While the node's links page looks like:
[image]

Other than that, you're stuck with some version of a `show mac address` routine on the switch.

Comment: please explain how you get the GUI screens , from the site installation I see how to install the packages on linux 4 but I have linux - 5 and the tool fit for linux 4 , about your GUI screens - how to create screens topology ? from the DEMO I not see this screens